# Extracting questions from docx file using python

Tags: python

I have a Django project in which I want the user to upload a docx file containing questions of MCQ/Fill in The Blanks type. I want to extract these questions and store individual questions in the database.

I have set up the database, but couldn't find anything to extract the questions from the docx file.

I can read the docx file using textract (https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which gives me a list of strings. But how do I check whether a string is a question or an option or just an instruction? Do I have to make specific rules to extract the questions, or is there any library in Python that can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share much more details, if the questions have a pattern, we can use reg expressions to extract questions/answers

Comment: There are some useful Natural Language Processing libraries in python that can help you, see this [link](https://elitedatascience.com/python-nlp-libraries), if the questions are simple you could use Regular Expresions to extract the questions.

Comment: @ThomasJohn I tried to use regex but it seems to me that it'll be too complicated and will work only for a certain kind of document. Here is a link to the document containing my observations about the question papers that I want to parse: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nfmJLq9adeeWrjkDuO8HXxQK7-u9CFtGC0KuKNyEzNo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JorgeRodriguezMolinuevo Thanks! I'll take a look at the link you sent.